# set django form initial value to blank when the filed is required

Tags: python, django

In Django forms how do I specify default value of a field to blank and force users to select one of choices.

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    notification_email = 
    forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("a","a"),("b","b")],initial="--",required=True)
```

Im using this, but it sets "a" as initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`TypedChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield). It's provide `empty_value` argument:

```
notification_email = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[("a","a"),("b","b")], empty_value="--", required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the example below, the default displayed value is `--`. Unless the user selects one of the valid options (`a` or `b`), the form fails to submit.

```py
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    notification_email = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[
            (None, "--"),
            ("a","a"),
            ("b","b"),
        ],
        initial=None,
        required=True,
    )
```